# How to Create Archive in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, archive

I want to display a archive page.
I want the Year as Parent Category then Month as Child and Then Post /Date to be displayed as Last child category in page. I have tried googling.

I have succeeded in getting the Year and Month, but not more than that.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ddblog");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblarchive group by aYear order by ayear desc ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){    
    echo "<div class='w_100 mb10' ><h2 class='heading3 bb2' style='padding-bottom: 10px;'>".$row['aYear']."</h2>";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblarchive where aYear=".$row['aYear']."");

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
        echo"<div class='w_100 fl'><h3 class='heading3'>".$row2['aMonth'].
            "</h3><div class='para'><ul class='listim'><li><a href=".$row2['aLink'].
            " class='co1'>".$row2['aDesc']."</a></li></ul></div></div> ";    
    }
    echo  "<a href='#' class='tn colrong2'>See More</a>";
 }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

[image: Archive]

Comment: i hope this is not your real password for the database in the first line...

Comment: As if you know which server it is. xD It's probably localhost.

Comment: it would help if there was the table definition and some test data so that we can see what we have to work with. As an 'SQLFiddle' would be really nice. :-)

Comment: @user3475736 The edit function on SO has a history wiki, so your database creentials are stil visable to anyone. Consider changing youre password for mysql user a9905550_ddblog on your mysql7.000*****.com machine.

Comment: You need to fetch the corresponding `YEAR()` in your fetched SQL row and then `GROUP BY` it accordingly. If you show us your DB scheme we would be better able to help.